# Mailcore2 on Android storeFlags operation hangs

Tags: android, mailcore2

I'm trying to set the delete flag on a message, and when I run `start()` on the storeFlags operation, it hangs, and the emulator says the application has stopped running.  Here's my code:

```
IndexSet set = IndexSet.indexSetWithIndex(message.uid());
IMAPOperation setDeleteFlagOperation = 
    MessagesSyncManager.singleton().session.storeFlagsByUIDOperation(
        "INBOX", set, IMAPStoreFlagsRequestKind.IMAPStoreFlagsRequestKindSet, 
        MessageFlag.MessageFlagDeleted);
setDeleteFlagOperation.start(this);
```

I've also tried using `storeFlagsByNumberOperation()` to create the operation with the same result.  I've made sure that I pass in a valid UID, or in the case of `storeFlagsByNumberOperation()`, a valid sequence number.  Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Of course, it's not supposed to stop the application. There might be an issue with mailcore on android. It's still needs lots of testing. It will be great if you could help investigating the issue. Thanks!

Comment: Could you create file an issue on github? Thanks.